# Folders created through "Save As..." dialog not immediately visible in Finder

Tags: finder, macos, folders

[image]

One my favorite OS X features is creating folders through the "Save As..." dialog. But recently I've run into an issue. When I try to browse to folders recently created using the "Save As..." dialog, they are not visible in the Finder. Mysteriously, they *do appear* in applications' "Open" and "Save As..." dialogs. I have to relaunch the Finder (I used `killall Finder` in the Terminal) to get the folders to show up. When they appear, they don't disappear again, and the contents I saved are there and are intact.

How can I restore the Finder's ability to see all newly created folders as soon as they appear in the file system?

*One note: I've installed Hazel and Dropbox, which may have disturbed some Finder .plist file somewhere. Hazel is no longer installed, but Dropbox is.*

Answer (score 1):

I have that as well on my MBA with Mavericks, occasionally, even with things like screenshot that I have just taken not showing in finder. And the files can not be found with spotlight, nor are they hidden kind.

Have not found what causes it (still looking, since it is not reproducible event), but I use the keyboard shortcut to reset the finder after which it works again.

<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> then click on Finder Relaunch.

I know it is not a fix, but bit faster way then using terminal.

Comment: Alt or Opt? There's no Alt on standard Mac keyboards.

Comment: Helpful answer, although as you said, it's not a fix.

Comment: sorry alt = opt :) that is normally the keyboard short cut when you want to force quit a application.

Comment: An aside - all Mac keyboards used to actually have Option or Opt printed on the key. Some [including my own] actually say 'Alt' these days. UK Mac Pro Extended, wired.

Answer (score 0):

posted as an answer for formatting…

Does refreshing the Finder views work?
Try this script, save as an app…

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theWindows to every Finder window
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in theWindows
        set this_item to item i of theWindows
        set theView to current view of this_item
        if theView is list view then
            set current view of this_item to icon view
        else
            set current view of this_item to list view

        end if
        set current view of this_item to theView
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Just so I'm clear, would I need to run this app every time a folder failed to appear? Because I'm looking to prevent the issue, not resolve it once it happens. Ideally.

Comment: I'm afraid so. Anecdotally, I had similar random issues like yours, until I traded up my boot HD for an SSD. I have also been known to randomly push buttons in Cocktail & even CleanMyMac - though I'm of the opinion that the latter might get over-zealous on occasion.